# htaccess issues with non exist files

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress site with the following `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

However, it will show `200 OK` response (with showing the "Media Library" page in wordpress) with the following url:

`http://localhost/wp-admin/upload.php/user-new.php/66868`

It's intepreting **`upload.php` file which exist**, but the ideal response should be  **404 where `/user-new.php/66868` does not exist**

Any idea on this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the effect of the “path info” feature.

Apache realizes that `/wp-admin/upload.php` exists as a physical file, so it serves up that, and passes the rest of the requested URL on in the `PATH_INFO` environment variable.

[`AcceptPathInfo`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo)  is the name of the directive you can use to turn this off.